# Display grep output in column table

Tags: bash, shell, tabular

I need some help with a script that grabs info from `whois` to display the creation, expiry date and ns server of specific domain names.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat domain-file.txt  | while read line ; do
lLine="$(echo $line | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
echo "$lLine\t" >> table.csv;
sleep 3
echo "\n$lLine"
host=whois.nic.re
created=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'created:')
echo "$created\t" >> table.csv
sleep 2
expire=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'Expiry Date:')
echo "$expire\t" >> table.csv
sleep 2
nserver=$(whois -h $host $lLine | egrep -i 'nserver:')
echo "$nserver\t" >> table.csv
echo "------------------------------------------" >> table.csv
done
exit
```

Everything is working well except that I'm trying to display the result of my `grep` command in a table like this:

```
Domain          Created Date    Expiry date     NS
abcd.com        19/01/2018      19/01/2019      ns.abcd.com ns2.abcd.com
1234.com        19/01/2018      19/01/2019      ns.1234.com ns2.1234.com
```

Instead I'm getting an output like that:

```
abcd.com
Created date: 19/01/2018
Expiry date: 19/01/2019
nserver: ns.abcd.com
nserver: ns2.abcd.com
------------------------------------------
1234.com
Created date: 19/01/2018
Expiry date: 19/01/2019
nserver: ns.1234.com
nserver: ns2.1234.com
------------------------------------------
```

I have tried many ways with `sed` and `awk` but I always get messy table.
I'm pretty new with shell script so If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are those fixed column widths? If yes, state the number of characters in each column please. If not, please explain (in Engish) how to determine the column width.

Comment: Actually i want to organise the output in tables and i dont know how to determine the characters in each column but let's say as example 35 characters per column. Does this really matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this... Edit for your needs.

```
{ # opening a brace to collect and control I/O
  typeset -l line created expire ns                  # preset to lowercase
  # controlled width header
  printf "%-20s%-25s%-25sNS\n" Domain "Create Date" "Expiry Date"

  while read line                                    # downcases as it loads
  do # only read each domain once. Save and reuse.
     typeset -u data=$(whois $line)                  # this one upcases
     # %-14s is a 14 wide left-adjusted string
     printf "%-20s" "$line"
     # use a regex to account for variation in server output
     created=$( echo "$data" | egrep 'CREAT[^:]*:' ) # no -i needed
     printf "%-25s" "${created#*: }"                 # autotrim labels
     expire=$( echo "$data" | egrep 'EXPIR[^:]*:' )  # regex again
     printf "%-25s" "${expire#*: }"                  # autotrim
     echo "$data" | egrep 'N[^:]*SERVER:' |          # outputs multiple
       while read ns                                 # loop them
       do printf "${ns#*: } "                        # to easily autotrim
       done
     printf "\n"                                     # and end the line
  done
# now close the brace and define your stdin & stdout
} < domain-file.txt > table.csv

exit
```

Instead of "Created" I was getting "Creation". Sometimes Expiry in Expire or expiration. Find the simplest common data that gets what you need and doesn't give false positives. You could also use `egrep 'EXPIR(Y|E|ATION)[^:]*:'` or some such; extended regexes are your friend.

Using `domain-file.txt` of

```
YAHOO.com
GOOGLE.com
```

this gives me

```
Domain              Create Date              Expiry Date              NS
yahoo.com           1995-01-18t05:00:00z     2023-01-19t05:00:00z     ns1.yahoo.com ns2.yahoo.com ns3.yahoo.com ns4.yahoo.com ns5.yahoo.com
google.com          1997-09-15t04:00:00z     2020-09-14t04:00:00z     ns1.google.com ns2.google.com ns3.google.com ns4.google.com
```

I took the host var out; put yours back in as required.
Cheers. :)